# How can I activate (display) a view (floor plan or Level) using Revit API?

Tags: c#, revit-api, revitpythonshell, pyrevit, revit-2015

I am trying to activate a view using Revit API. What I want to do exactly is to display the level or floor plan view. So the view I want to activate ( I mean, I want this view to be actually shown on screen) already exists, and I can access its Id.

I have seen threads about creating, browsing, filtering views, but nothing on activating it... It's a Floor Plan view. (What I want is that by selecting a level/ floor plan, it displays that level/ floor plan on-screen(it's like opening that floor plan from the already existing Revit model to display on the user screen).

Comment: here is the ActiveView Property
https://www.revitapidocs.com/2022/b6adb74b-39af-9213-c37b-f54db76b75a3.htm

Comment: Hi, Abhijit I'm struggling to create something similar in Blazor, do you have any samples I may take a look at?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

[Revit api docs link for RequestViewChange Method](https://www.revitapidocs.com/2021.1/a2e920d4-2849-282e-c25f-40a4d2cbef2d.htm)

use `uidoc.RequestViewChange("Your View")` sometimes view can't be changed while on processing transactions. On such case Force Close the Transaction. before this line `uidoc.RequestViewChange("Your View")`

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example how to switch to the default 3d-view
https://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2011/09/activate-a-3d-view.html

you can do the same with all other available views like this

```c
    UIApplication uiapp = commandData.Application;
    UIDocument uidoc = uiapp.ActiveUIDocument;
  
    uidoc.ActiveView = yourview;
```

to create a view from a level your code can look like this

```cs
ViewFamilyType viewFamilyType = (from elem in new 
    FilteredElementCollector(doc)
    .OfClass(typeof(ViewFamilyType))
    let type = elem as ViewFamilyType
    where type.ViewFamily == ViewFamily.FloorPlan
    select type).FirstOrDefault();

using (Transaction t = new Transaction(doc))
{
    t.Start("Create View");
    var floorPlan = ViewPlan.Create(doc, viewFamilyType.Id, yourLevel.Id);
    floorPlan.Name = "NewView";
    t.Commit();
}
```

Comment: I have tried this. but I couldn't get the "view" to set to the "uidoc.ActiveView".

Comment: Unable to cast Autodesk.Revit.DB.Level to Autodesk.Revit.DB.View

Comment: you have to create a view from your level. use one of the available view types https://www.revitapidocs.com/2017/76bee86d-3c34-7ee1-4349-cd7abcbf3d78.htm
and then .Create(level.Document, viewTypeId, level.Id);

Comment: I have created a ribbon tab and a button which opens a "WPF" from, in that there is drop down and here I have collected the levels/floor plan(e.g. Level1, Level2, etc. ) from the Revit project. So here I want to open ( I have added a button....click to "Show")  a particular level/floor plan by selecting that particular level.

Comment: Can we filter views by Levels ??

Comment: in the view members there is a LevelId. With this id you can filter your views by level
https://www.revitapidocs.com/2019/d8d64cdb-46b7-6486-7cb5-07178b65a87b.htm

Comment: I have created a ribbon tab and a button which opens a "WPF" from, in that there is drop down and here I have collected the levels/floor plan(e.g. Level1, Level2, etc. ) from the Revit project. So here I want to open ( I have added a button....click to "Show") a particular level/floor plan by selecting that particular level.   Does anyone get that??

Answer (score 0):

Super easy to do:

```
# normally you have the ui set at the start of your script
ui = __revit__.ActiveUIDocument 

# then just set the ActiveView as your view (not the ViewId)
ui.ActiveView = yourView
```

Answer (score 0):

FilteredElementCollector viewCollector = new FilteredElementCollector(doc);

```
                viewCollector.OfClass(typeof(View));

                foreach (Element viewElement in viewCollector)
                {
                        yourview = (View)viewElement;
                      
                        break;  
                }
            }

            uidoc.ActiveView = yourview;
```