# View/interact with dwg or Revit floor plan in Blazor

Tags: blazor, revit-api, dwg

I would like to view and interact with my dwg floor plan using Blazor.
What I mean by interact, is just see the specific room that was clicked and go back to the main floor plan.

Is there any library or something that can help with this?
There is also something called `Revit` to create floor plans, but again how would I display this...
A similar question for Revit was asked here: [How can I activate (display) a view (floor plan or Level) using Revit API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69797909/how-can-i-activate-display-a-view-floor-plan-or-level-using-revit-api)

I have seen it before on a home automation demo, so it is possible, but I don't know how to recreate it.